# Docker enable virtualization error on windows 10

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-machine

when I open the docker I got an error

Enable virtualization on your computer

Check that hardware-assisted virtualization (either Intel VMX or AMD SVM) and Data Execution Prevention (sometimes labeled XD or Execute Disable or NX) are enabled in your BIOS.

Check your bootloader is configured to launch Hyper-V.

then I tried with the below command and restart the system

**dism.exe /Online /Enable-Feature:Microsoft-Hyper-V /All**

then I restart the system and again open the docker

but I got two popup error message

1. System.Exception:
   checking windows features: Post "http://ipc/windowsfeatures/check": open \.\pipe\dockerBackendV2: The system cannot find the file specified.
   at Docker.Engines.LinuxHyperVEngine.d__16.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\4.21.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Engines\LinuxHyperVEngine.cs:line 103
   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Docker.ApiServices.StateMachines.TaskExtensions.d__0.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\4.21.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.ApiServices\StateMachines\TaskExtensions.cs:line 29
   --- End of stack trace
2. unhandled exception has occurred in your application. if you click continue the application will ignore this error and attempt to continue. if you click quit the application will close immediately.

if I click the continue button and again open the docker it shows Failed to start the Docker Engine
Get troubleshooting help from the Docker documentation⁠